# Kann ich bitte sie ein paar fragen? but in a polite form

Tags: learning

I'm trying to learn German. How can I ask somebody (e.g. in a cafe) to help me with that?

I want to say something like that:

> – Hi, I'm Peter. Do you have a minute for me?
>   -- ...
>   -- I'm learning German. Can I ask you a few questions?
>   –– (me trying to ask some questions)

I translated it into something like that:

> – Hallo, ich bin Peter. Haben Sie eine minute für mich?
>   -- ...
>   -- Ich bin Deutsch lernen. Kann ich bitte Sie ein paar Fragen?

Is it a polite form? How can I ask politely?
I want to annoy people as less as possible

Comment: Put in reopen queue because the above close reason appears not to fit.

Comment: Small tip: In German you can use the Konjunktiv form to ask as passive as possible. But it is already advanced German.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Hallo, ich bin Peter.

correct

---

> wrong: Haben Sie eine minute fur mich?
>   correct: Haben Sie eine Minute für mich?

In German all nouns need to be capitalized: wrong: *minute*. correct: *Minute*
The dots on umlauts are not optional, they are mandatory: wrong: *fur*. correct: *für*
If you can't type umlauts, type an *e* after the vowel (*ue* instead of *ü*) because the dots on the vowels developed over the centuries from an e after this vowels.
wrong: *fur*. acceptable: *fuer*. correct: *für*

---

> wrong: Ich bin Deutsch lernen.
>   correct: Ich lerne Deutsch.

German has nothing like progressive form (ing-form). So something like »ich bin lernen« simply is wrong in German. Both *"I learn"* and *"I am learning"* translate to *»ich lerne«* in German.

---

> wrong: Kann ich bitte Sie ein paar Fragen?
>   correct: Kann ich Sie bitte etwas fragen?
>   or: Kann ich Ihnen bitte ein paar Fragen stellen?

Both forms are good style and polite.

Learn:

- Fragen = questions (a noun in plural form)
- fragen = to ask (a verb in its infinite form)

Remember the rule about nouns I mentioned above: Always write nouns with an uppercase first letter. This rule only applies to nouns, not to verbs! (Well, also the first word of a sentence needs to be capitalized, no matter what kind it is.)

So, the sentence you wrote contains no verb, which means: It isn't a sentence. An English equivalent might be:

> Can I you some question please?

So you need a verb, and *"to ask"* is *»fragen«* in German, which gives:

> Kann ich Sie bitte etwas fragen?
>   Please, can I ask you something?

But in German there is a very common phrase. In English, the noun *question* is very different from the verb *to ask*, while in German they are equal, except from upper/lowercase writing of the first letter. So a direct translation would be:

> to ask a question
>   eine Frage fragen

This is grammatically correct, but very bad style. Never use the verb *fragen* together with the noun *Fragen* in the same sentence. Use this phrase instead:

> to ask a question
>   eine Frage stellen

(verbatime translation: *to put/place a question*)

Comment: Hubert is of course right that, if you do not have ä, ö, ü available you can replace them with ae, oe, ue. However, nowadays, as you are writing on a computer, I do not see a legitimate excuse for not spelling things correctly. The ae-oe-ue-thing came up in a time when there were only mechanical typewriters, and people in other countries simply did not have the types for *deutsche Umlaute* in their localized machines. Today it is just a question of giving your keyboard the correct settings.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: And still, even in 2017/18 people even here in the German spoken Austria type *oe* into their computers instead of *ö* when they write my name: Six weeks ago (End of November 2017) I broke my shoulder. In the hospital I had to show my ID card, which clearly says *»Hubert Schölnast«* (with ö), but the lady there typed *»Hubert Schoelnast«* into the computer (using a German Keyboard). The effect is: When I sit in the waiting room, and they call me for x-ray, they say: »Herr Scho-elnast, Röntgenzimmer zwei« instead of »Herr Schölnast, ...«

Comment: As was stated correctly, the continouus form (*I am learning*) has no direct counterpart in German. As an aside: *learning* can be one of two different grammatical forms: the gerund, which is translated as the infinitive (*lernen*) and the present participle, which is translated as the Partizip I (*lernend*, which doesn't work here because of the aforementioned lack of a continouus form in German)

Comment: Fixed an issue with an umlaut and added a German keyboard.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Na, dann hoffe ich mal, dass die Róntgenapparate besser waren als die Computer ;-)